# How to auto fill form fills based on data from a table?

Tags: forms, coldfusion

I have a form which the data is being submitted to a table.

Using the column 'month_date_show' I would like to auto fill the form
if that date exist in the column in the table, since it will only be submit once a month.
If the date does exist in the table then the user will be able to edit those results, if it does not exist
then no need to auto fill the user will submit new results for that month.

Not sure if this is something that will have to use ajax or java script to make it happen.
Right now I hard coded the values in the form , but i would like to make it dynamic.

```
<cfquery datasource ="intranet" name="GetSummary">
            SELECT * from cse_result_summary    
        </cfquery>

<form method="post" name="myform" action="cse_execoffice_datepicker_test.cfm" onsubmit="return validateForm()">     
                    <table >
                    <tr>
                        <td>    
                        <input type="text" id="dpMonthYear"  NAME="month_date_show" value="9/2014" style="width:80px;" />
                        </td>
                    <td>
                        &nbsp;<img alt="Month/Year Picker" onclick="showCalendarControl('dpMonthYear');" 
                        src="pictures/datepicker.gif" />
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>
            <table >
            <tbody>     
                <tr>
                    <td>  Rising Star Award Winner:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="risingstar" size="50" class="get_branches_departments_displaynum" value="john"></td>       
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Department Average:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="risingstar_ave" size="8" class="get_branches_departments_displaynum" value="5"></td>
                </tr>

                    <tr>
                    <td>  Rising Star Award Winner runner-up:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="risingstar_runner" size="50" class="get_branches_departments_displaynum" value="joe"></td>

                </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>

            <p><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"></p>
            </form>
```

Comment: The google search string you seek is "coldfusion auto suggest".

Comment: I don't think it be auto suggest, when a user click on month_date_show, they be able to choose what ever month they want, i thought auto suggest , suggest what the user types ?

Comment: Oops, I misunderstood the question.  You are looking for a way to populate the value attribute of your form fields?  That can be done with ColdFusion by itself.  What do you want the value to be?

Comment: i want the value to populate from the table depending if the date(month/year) for that collumn exist in the table,
if it does not exist on table then no need to populate form

Comment: If by table, you mean the HTML table; this resides on the client side and ColdFusion is on the server side. You would need to use some kind of Ajax/JavaScript to do it.  If by table, you mean the database table; you can utilize the answer I provided.

Comment: Well, if there is only one form per month, you get a maximum of twelve forms a year.  That's not a lot of data.  You can just populate the data using ColdFusion into a JavaScript array.  Put an onChange attribute in that month_date_show field to populate the data from the JavaScript array if the entered month and year exist in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you are actually storing the month and year of the forms submitted, and assuming that the users are submitting form for the current month and current year (i.e. it is September 2014 now and the users would be submitting form for 09/2014 but not submitting form for any other form, ex. 08/2014), then at the time when a user gets to your page, you already know whether a new form is needed by searching against the database.

You can then populate the form accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. If you don't care if the user refreshes the page, just submit the form onChange, run the query to select information for that date

```
SELECT winner, average, runup 
FROM tablename 
WHERE datecol = <cfqueryparam type=<whatevertypeappropriate> value="#val_name#">
```

In your form just have the **value** field value dynamically assigned.

```
<input type="text" name="winner" value="#queryname.winner#">
```

If you don't want them to have to resubmit the form, I think there'll have to be some kind of binding.